# assign class objects instead of the actual script class to unity game objects in unity c#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to create a game in Unity C# in which the player will add as much as drones he needs as game objects to the game world. Therefore, I made a drone prefab and later in runtime I ask the number of drones the player wants to have (e.x. n numbers) and instantiate the prefab n times. 
The script which is attached to the drone prefab is called drone_script. 
Therefore, I am having a drone_script class as a general class. This class has an attribute  (let's call it subscriber) which should have different unique values for each drone. So, it is created as a null reference in drone_script general class and later in runtime, I will initialize it.
During runtime, I create n (the same numbers as the drone game objects) objects from this class and assign their subscriber attribute different values.

This is how it looks:

```
     some_class
     {
         for (int i = 0; i < number_of_Drones; ++i)
                {
                    drones_script[i] = new drone_script(); 
                    \\ here I am creating n objects of my general drone_script class
                    drones_script[i].drone_subscriber = a unique value;
                    \\ here I am assigning to each of the drone objects' drone_subscriber attribute a different value.
                    drco = new Vector3((float)0, (float)1, (float)0);
                    drones[i] = Instantiate(Resources.Load("drone"), drco, 
                    Quaternion.Euler(-90, 0, 90)) as GameObject;
    \\I instatiate the drone prefab in unity game world here.
                }
  }


drone_script
{
 public ROSBridgeSubscriber drone_subscriber;
 void Start() { \\some code }
 void FixedUpdate () { \\some code }
}
```

My problem is when the drone game objects are created in unity, the general class drone_script is attached to them and because of this their subscriber attribute is null. However, I need the drone_script[i] object to be assigned to them as their script, not the general drone_script itself. Because only then each drone game object has its corresponding subscriber attribute value from before even the start function is being called.
Am I thinking correctly?
If yes, how can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I suggest you to assign dronePrefab using editor or in Start method of "some_class" because Resources.Load("drone") might be resource consuming, since you load a drone resource "n" times.

Now your specific problem, you don't need to create new instances of "drone_script" because as you mentioned yourself, each drone that you create has his own "drone_script". So basically what we need to do is:

1. Instantiate drone and save his reference (as GameObject)
2. Get that drone's "drone_script" (using GetComponent<>(); )
3. Save that script reference in our array so we can use it later
4. Adjust some variables of that script now or later in the game

Something like that should work. In code everything should be something like this (didn't test, might be some miss types)

```
some_class
 {
     public GameObject dronePrefab;
     for (int i = 0; i < number_of_Drones; ++i)
     {
        // Step 1.
        drco = new Vector3((float)0, (float)1, (float)0);
        drones[i] = Instantiate(dronePrefab, drco, 
        Quaternion.Euler(-90, 0, 90)) as GameObject;
        // Steps 2 & 3
        drones_script[i] = drones[i].GetComponent<drone_script>();
        // Step 4
        drones_script[i].drone_subscriber = a unique value;            
    }
}
```

EDIT:
Just to point it out: drone_script has to be attached to drone prefab

Comment: Correction: `drones[i].GetComponent<drone_script>();`, the T parameter needs to be the class, not a string of the class's name.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. Do I need to attach drone_script to drone prefab too?

Comment: I've edited as @Draco18s pointed out.  Yes, drone_script must be a part of the drone prefab. What is the problem that it is not working ? Debug and write us what is the problem, but I believe it should be ok if everything is done correctly

Comment: You can change the type of dronePrefab to the drone_script if it is a MonoBehaviour and save yourself from having to do GetComponent.